# Import stl models PyQt3D and Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build my application to .exe with PyInstaller, but it seems, that PyQt3D module doesn't imports PyQt3D module.
It is impossible to build application with Qt3D with PyInstaller, or I need some extra configuration for this? I tried to add PyQt3D module in hidden-imports, but still have an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, Qt3DCore, Qt3DExtras, Qt3DRender, QtGui, QtCore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.Qt3DInput'
[13512] Failed to execute script main
```

I passed --hidden-import PyQt5.Qt3DInput to PyInstaller.
But still, I've got this:

```
Qt3D.Renderer.Jobs: unsupported format encountered (stl)
```

When I'm running my application in PyCharm everething is OK.
Maybe anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Find out that to start import models with setSource() I need to add PyQt5/Qt/plugins/geometryloaders to PyQt5. So full command to build onefile PyQt3D Application is:

```
pyinstaller %input_file% --onefile --hidden-import PyQt5.Qt3DInput --add-data "venv/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/geometryloaders";"PyQt5/Qt/plugins/geometryloaders"
```